# Angular dynamic form for array of strings

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I've got a news with multiple paragraphs in it. What I'm trying to do is to add a form control to each paragraphs so that I can update them individually.

This is how the data looks like

```
{
    "newsId": "42352",
    "title": "Service is now available",
    "body": [
        "Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed",
            "Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed",

    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

My template looks something like this

```
<div class="form-group" >
   <md-input-container class="md-block">
       <textarea mdInput type="text" rows="6" cols="" [ngModel]="news?.getBody()" class="texta" name="body" placeholder="Paragraph" #body [formControl]="updateNewsFormGroup.controls['body']"></textarea>
   </md-input-container>
</div>
```

In my component I've this for now

```
this.updateNewsFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
        'title': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)])],
        'body': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
        'newParagraph': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])]
    });
```

How can I assign a controller for each paragraphs Individually?

Comment: what do you mean by  "assign a controller"  ? A new form controler or a new angular controller ?

Comment: a new form controller